# Apply css class on a specific control

Tags: html, css

I have a class attribute that's applied on all label controls, but now I need to change the attributes of some labels in my solution, how can I do that??

This is my current class, I want to keep it, and I need a another specified class

```
.form-container fieldset label{}
```

Comment: On which `label` elements do you want this specific CSS to apply? Without specific information this is just a guessing game, or a theoretical discussion (which we don't do).

Comment: on label element @David Thomas

Comment: Yes, I got that. *which* `label` elements? What's your HTML? How do the `label`s you want to specifically, and differently, affect differ from those you *don't* want to affect/style in this way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to the labels you want to change taht might look somwthing like this:

```
<label class="someclass">stuff</label>
```

and add 1 more class

```
<label class="someclass someotherclass">stuff</label>
```

and then in your css file after the `.someclass{/*stuff*/}` add

```
.someotherclass{/*stuff*/}
```

Comment: No problem take care.

Answer (score 0):

On the labels you want to change attributes on, you could apply a new class or id. Alternatively you could use the css nth child selector if you know the numeric order of the labels you want to change.